# How to store hadoop data into oracle

Tags: oracle, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, sqoop

My final table is in Hive(HDFS)

1) I have tired "Sqoop" 
2) sql loader 
3) oraoop

Performance of all are very discouraging ,while we are putting data into sql database

have to import 1 TB file and 1 GB is taking over all 8 Min (1297372920 Rows) in 5 node cluster with sqoop ,oraoop,sql loader

Comment: so, where is your question?

Comment: fro loading data into oracle through sqoop,oraoop,sql loader they all taking same time so how can we export data from hadoop to oracle in fast speed

Answer (score 0):

Your Sqoop export to Oracle speed will be determined by various factors including data size/characteristics, network performance and perhaps most importantly the target database server's configuration. Since the current release of Sqoop doesn't allow for use of "direct" in exporting data to Oracle the optimizations available in this use case are limited. I'd strongly encourage you to review the documentation (http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_export_literal) and try to get yourself into a position where you can work with incremental imports/exports if possible since you're displeased with latency using your 1tb dataset. Perhaps go with an initial full load of your entire desired dataset and find a way to only update incrementally from there.